# Why is padding of 1px different to padding of 0px for floating div - all browsers?

Tags: html, css

Check this HTML example - the only difference is

`padding-top:0px;`
vs
`padding-top:1px;`

Yet the 2nd example, the div is offset by a completely different amount?

```
<div style="clear: both; margin:0px; padding-top:0px; border: 0px">
    <div style="float:right;width:300px">
        <div style="margin:10px;border:1px solid silver">A Title</div>
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
    </div>

    <div style="">
        <div style="margin: 10px; border: 1px solid silver">A Title</div>
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
    </div>
</div>


<div style="clear: both; margin:0px; padding-top:1px; border: 0px">
    <div style="float:right;width:300px">
        <div style="margin:10px;border:1px solid silver">A Title</div>
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
    </div>

    <div style="">
        <div style="margin: 10px; border: 1px solid silver">A Title</div>
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

THis has been tried across chrome/firefox/ie/safari, and it must be something obvious that I'm missing?

Hope some bright spark can help!

Comment: Seems same to me in FF in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/SCF9h/

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is defined in [8.3.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first
>   in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top
>   border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.

Without padding the content column top margin collapses.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'problem' is in **collapsing margins**, which is well defined behaviour in the CSS standards and as such identically implemented in all browser engines.

The short summary is that when 2 vertically adjoining elements have margins, they collapse onto eachother to satisfy the largest value. Because you are inserting padding at the top of the bottom element, there are no longer elements with adjoining margins, making the collapse impossible and causing the distance to be both margins plus the padding.

See [the CSS box model standards here for the full rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), specifically in this case:

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> - [...]
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them
> - [...]

Answer (score 0):

if you set the margin of the third div, it takes from top 10px of margin from its container

try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/7wnr4/**

```
<div style="clear: both; margin:0px; padding-top:0px; border: 0px;">
    <div style="float:right;width:300px">
        <div style="margin-top:0px;border:1px solid silver">A Title</div>
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
        Sidebar<br />
    </div>

    <div style="">
        <div style="margin-top: 0px; border: 1px solid silver">A Title</div>
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content<br />
    </div>
</div>
```